# Parsing an echo in php

Tags: php, parsing, echo, isset

I have an email form in php which has 3 possible appearances.

Firstly, when the submit button has not been used, I want it to appear standard.

Secondly, when submit HAS been clicked and no data was set in it.

Thirdly, when data was input acceptably, I want to display what was input.

However, I am a total php newbie and I don't seem to be able to get it right.

```
<?php
    if(isset(sent)) {
        if(isset($_POST['forename']) && !empty($_POST['forename']) {
            echo('<input class="tbox" type="text" name="forename" value="$POST['forename']" /><br>');
        } else {
            echo('<input class="tbox bad" type="text" name="forename" value=""/><br>');
        }
    } else {
        echo('<input class="tbox" type="text" name="forename" value="" /><br>') ;
    }
?>
```

I assume the error is the "s and 's.  I get an unexpected ) exception.  How should the echo lines be constructed to avoid this?

Comment: The nested if was missing a ).  I had tried a similar solution to both suggested earlier, but it seems that wasn't the problem.  Validating special chars is very useful though, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
echo('<input class="tbox" type="text" name="forename" value="$POST['forename']" /><br>');
```

Variables don't get parsed inside single quotes, only in double quotes.

An easy solution would be:

```
echo '<input class="tbox" type="text" name="forename" value="' . htmlspecialchars($POST['forename']) . '" /><br>';
```

Note that I have used `htmlspecialchars` to avoid your variable breaking the html. You also don't need to use parenthesis when you use `echo` (doesn't harm though...).

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the error:

```
echo('<input class="tbox" type="text" name="forename" value="$POST['forename']" /><br>');
```

You have to concat the value with the two other parts of the string and it's `$_POST` instead of `$POST`:

```
'[…]value="' . $_POST['forename'] . '"[…]'
```

You should also at least use `htmlentities` on the value that an input won't break your HTML:

```
htmlentities($_POST['forename'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```